# Using symbolically the coordinates of an intersection point between curves for filling the area below a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I would like to fill the area under the rectangles that have the origin and the working point `(Q_1, H_1)` and `(Q_2, H_2)`, respectively, obtained as intersections between the two red curves with the blue one.
I managed to pinpoint the intersection point and to draw the segments defining the rectangle, and then I tried to use `fill between` but the output was coloured trapezoid between the segment and the whole horizontal axis.
I started thinking the missing element is the right end-point of the interval over which the horizontal axis path is defined (which has to be `Q_1` and not `xmax`), so I looked for a solution to this problem, without any relevant success.
I am not very familiar with this package (that is the reason why maybe this question is almost a duplicate but I cannot determine it), so I have not been able to use properly `let` or `pgfextractx` functions for this purpose.
How can I reference symbolically the abscissa of the intersection point `(OP1)` and use it for defining properly the useful interval for `fill between`?

Here follows my attempt:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel,calc,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{figure}[H] %% figure is closed
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot[name path =pump,blue,domain=0:1] {-0.5*x^2+1};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= ${(Q_1,H_1)}$ ] (OP1) at (intersection-1);
\path [name intersections={of=load2 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= ${(Q_2,H_2)}$ ] (OP2) at (intersection-1);

\draw[name path=opv1] (OP1) -- (OP1|-0,0);
\draw[name path=oph1] (OP1) -- (0,0 |- OP1);
\draw[name path=opv2] (OP2) -- (OP2|-0,0);
\draw[name path=oph2] (OP2) -- (0,0 |- OP2);

\path[name path=zero]
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

\addplot[orange]fill between[of=oph1 and zero];
\end{axis}

\foreach \point in {OP1,OP2}
\fill [red] (\point) circle (2pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{System working point}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: @gernot I was already rather aware that my code lacked something and that the output had to be necessarily a trapezoidal shape. I wanted to understand how to trim suitably the fill between command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if all you need is two rectangles, then `fill between` is kind of an overcomplication, you can just use `\fill (x,y) rectangle (u,v);`. You already have the coordinates. Below I also added the `backgrounds` library, and placed the rectangles inside a `scope` environment with `[on background layer]`, so that the rectangles are placed behind the plot lines.

I used `\filldraw`, but if you don't want the border drawn, change that to `\fill`, and remove the `draw=black` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel,calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
ticks=none,
]
\addplot[name path =pump,blue,domain=0:1] {-0.5*x^2+1};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
\addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

\path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= ${(Q_1,H_1)}$ ] (OP1) at (intersection-1);
\path [name intersections={of=load2 and pump}]; 
\coordinate [label= ${(Q_2,H_2)}$ ] (OP2) at (intersection-1);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\filldraw[fill=orange!50,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle node {foo} (OP2);
\filldraw[fill=blue!80!red!50!white,draw=black] (0,0-|OP2) rectangle node {bar} (OP1);
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\foreach \point in {OP1,OP2}
  \fill [red] (\point) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I had not even imagined to use rectangles directly, it is a very simple solution.

Comment: @Vexx23, if you find the answers useful you could think of [up-voting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) them and besides that [accept](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the most useful answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: @StefanPinnow Can't I accept both your answers (since they provide elegant solutions using different approaches)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is there a simple method for placing a text inside the rectangle?

Comment: @Vexx23 Several, for some text in the middle of it, add `node {text}` right after `rectangle`, see updated answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Another plain solution, another statement of gratitude.

Answer (score 4):

As Torbjørn T. and Gernot already stated, I am also not 100% sure what you really want to achieve. But I guess the answer of [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365796/95441) is pretty much what you are searching for.

So this is pretty much the same answer, but using the `fill between` features.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        intersections,
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xlabel=$Q$,ylabel=$H$,
        ticks=none,
    ]
        \addplot[blue,domain=0:1,name path=pump] {-0.5*x^2+1};
        \addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load1] {0.5*x^2+0.4*x+0.5};
        \addplot[red,domain=0:1,name path=load2] {2*x^2+1.6*x+0.5};

        \path [name intersections={of=load1 and pump}];
            \coordinate [label= ${(Q_1,H_1)}$ ] (OP1) at (intersection-1);
        \path [name intersections={of=load2 and pump}];
            \coordinate [label= ${(Q_2,H_2)}$ ] (OP2) at (intersection-1);

        \draw [name path=opv1] (OP1) -- (OP1 |- 0,0);
        \draw [name path=oph1] (OP1) -- (0,0 |- OP1);
        \draw [name path=opv2] (OP2) -- (OP2 |- 0,0);
        \draw [name path=oph2] (OP2) -- (0,0 |- OP2);

        \path [name path=zero]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);

        \addplot [orange] fill between [
            of=oph1 and zero,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % in order to achieve the desired result you can add a `soft clip'
            % path which cuts off the unwanted rest not inside of this `soft
            % clip' path and you need (in this case) also add `reverse=true'
            % explicitly, otherwise you get another unwanted result
            reverse=true,
            soft clip={
                % (depending on what you exactly need use one the following
                % starting corrdinates)
%                (OP2 |- 0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
                    rectangle
                (OP1)
            },
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        ];

        % add some text centered in the rectangle (as requested in the comments)
        \path
%            % (to show how it is drawn ...)
%            [draw,dashed]
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
                    -- node [pos=0.5] {some text} (OP1);
        ;

    \end{axis}

    \foreach \point in {OP1,OP2} {
        \fill [red] (\point) circle (2pt);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: The commented starting coordinate is the right one, the desired area to fill is the one of the rectangle from (0,0) to (Q1,H1) . Your solution is extremely clear and explanatory, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to add some text centred inside the 'fill between' area?

Comment: @Vexx23, sure. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, so a new stealth line is built after 'fill between' scope. Can I ask you which is the role of [pos=0.5]? It seems it force the node to be positioned at 0.5*length of the path, is it so?

Comment: @Vexx23, yes, `[pos=0.5]` is the default value and thus can be omitted. But if not someone wants to position the text somewhere else maybe he/she than has an idea -- together with the commented part -- how to achieve it without the need of asking again ... ;) And regarding the stealth line: Yes, you have to do something like this when you are using the `fill between` feature to fill the area, because there you cannot (to my knowledge) simply add a trailing path.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-plot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% The blue-coloured graph.
\def\aA{-0.5}
\def\bA{0}
\def\cA{1}
\def\fA(#1){(\aA*(#1)^2+\bA*(#1)+\cA)}

% The "first" red-coloured graph.
\def\aB{2}
\def\bB{1.6}
\def\cB{0.5}
\def\fB(#1){(\aB*(#1)^2+\bB*(#1)+\cB)}

% The "second" red-coloured graph.
\def\aC{0.5}
\def\bC{0.4}
\def\cC{0.5}
\def\fC(#1){(\aC*(#1)^2+\bC*(#1)+\cC)}

% Intersection points, x-coordinates.
\def\xAB{\fpeval{(-(\bA-\bB)-sqrt((\bA-\bB)^2-4*(\aA-\aB)*(\cA-\cB)))/(2*(\aA-\aB))}}
\def\xAC{\fpeval{(-(\bA-\bC)-sqrt((\bA-\bC)^2-4*(\aA-\aC)*(\cA-\cC)))/(2*(\aA-\aC))}}

\begin{document}

{\psset{
   xunit = 6,
   yunit = 3,
   dimen = m,
   algebraic
 }
\begin{pspicture}(1.2,1.5)
 {\psset{fillstyle = solid}
  \psframe[
    fillcolor = orange!60
  ](0,0)(\xAB,\fpeval{\fA(\xAB)})
  \rput(\fpeval{0.5*\xAB},\fpeval{0.5*\fA(\xAB)}){cat}
  \psframe[
    fillcolor = blue!60
  ](\xAB,0)(\xAC,\fpeval{\fA(\xAC)})
  \rput(\fpeval{0.5*(\xAC+\xAB)},\fpeval{0.5*\fA(\xAC)}){dog}}
  \psaxes[
    ticks = none,
    labels = none
  ]{->}(0,0)(-0.05,-0.1)(0.8,1.5)[$Q$,120][$H$,330]
  \psplot[
    linecolor = blue
  ]{0}{0.8}{\fA(x)}
  \psplot[
    linecolor = red
  ]{0}{0.4}{\fB(x)}
  \psplot[
    linecolor = red
  ]{0}{0.8}{\fC(x)}
  \psdots[
    dotstyle = o,
    fillcolor = red
  ](\xAB,\fpeval{\fA(\xAB)})(\xAC,\fpeval{\fA(\xAC)})
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the values of the coefficients of the three second degree polynomials and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly. (You have to change the plot ranges and axes ranges manually, if needed.)

**Addition**

If you add

```
\uput[90](\xAB,\fpeval{\fA(\xAB)}){$(G_{1},H_{1})$}
\uput[90](\xAC,\fpeval{\fA(\xAC)}){$(G_{2},H_{2})$}
```

to the drawing, you will get the labels of the two intersection points.